# matching columns with nearly similar values in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

I have 2 columns A and B with persons names (more than 100 values per column):

```
       Column A                  Column B             Column C

1     John Brett                Rise Matthew          Bret John

2     Dan Bond                  Bret John              Bonde Dan

3     Matthew Rice              Bonde Dan           Rise Matthew
```

As you can see,it's the same name written in both columns but typed differently.How can I match them?

I want to get the results in colunm C as above

Using Vlookup in column C for example:
Vlookup(B1,$A$1:$A$3,1,TRUE) didn't help .

Comment: What do you mean "match them"? What is your expected output?

Comment: It's really hopeless with worksheet functions. Also tough with VBA, if you want to try it search the internet for "fuzzy match".

Comment: For example in Column C, I want to see the values of column B matching the similar values in Column A

Comment: In the time you spend fiddling with fuzzy matching you could probably manually check 100 rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use in column c the Formula start in C1

3 in left(A1,3) is the smallest length of matching name like Dan, B3 is the last entry in column B and you can drag it down, `#REF!` means no match and I have inserted Iferror for that reason:
`=IFERROR(INDIRECT(IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH("*" & LEFT(A1,3)& "*",$B$1:$B$3,0)),"B"& MATCH("*" & LEFT(A1,3) &"*",$B$1:$B$3,0),"no match"),TRUE),"")`

Comment: Great, this solved my problem.